XGboost prediction is worse when unknow and missing data are encoded to different values
I'm working on a classification problem with categorical features. My dataset has missing values, which I'd prefer not to impute. Additionally, my test data contains categories not seen during training.
I've tried two encoding methods:
OrdinalEncoder with NaN and a placeholder: I used OrdinalEncoder to represent missing values as NaN and unseen categories as a large number (100000). I then defined these features as categorical (using astype('category')).
Direct conversion to 'category': I directly converted categorical features to the 'category' data type, allowing the model to handle unseen categories automatically.
Surprisingly, method 2 performs significantly better. I expected method 1 to be more effective with its explicit encoding of missing and unseen categories. Why might method 2 be outperforming method 1?

Can you share the code you used to compare the two encoding methods?
